# Attach a texture to a json object

Tags: three.js, blender

I can't get textures applied to a loaded json file. It works on a plane I dropped into the scene but not the object I'm loading (although I can change properties like metalness, etc).

Here is the where I am:

```
const towerObj = new THREE.ObjectLoader()

towerObj.load( "./3dassets/models/buiding.json",  function (object) {
    let tower = object
    scene.add(tower)

    const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("./3dassets/materials/Concrete.png")
    const bumpMap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("./3dassets/materials/Concrete_nrm.png")

    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping
    texture.repeat.set( 0.1, 0.1 )
    bumpMap.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping
    bumpMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping
    bumpMap.repeat.set( 0.1, 0.1 )

    tower.traverse( function (child) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            child.castShadow = true
            child.receiveShadow = true

            child.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial()
            child.material.map = texture
            child.material.bumpMap = bumpMap
            child.material.needsUpdate = true
            child.material.roughness = 0.1
            child.material.metalness = 0
            child.color = 'rgb(244,244,244)'
            console.log(child.name)

        }
    });


});
```

Here is a simplified version of the object (I removed most references to vertices, normals and faces otherwise it would crash the browser):

```
{
"metadata": {
    "version": 4.5,
    "type": "Object",
    "generator": "Object3D.toJSON"
},
"geometries": [
    {
        "uuid": "2920CDAB-6DEC-4BEB-9BFB-C794B33A5AFB",
        "type": "Geometry",
        "data": {
            "vertices": [0.720958,8.47758],
            "normals": [-0.448833,0.782579],
            "faces": [50,0,48,47,0,0,1,2,3,50,48,95,]
        }
    }],

"object": {
    "uuid": "EE10C174-4F45-45B3-80E6-8AA488B29F34",
    "type": "Mesh",
    "name": "tower",
    "castShadow": true,
    "receiveShadow": true,
    "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
    "geometry": "2920CDAB-6DEC-4BEB-9BFB-C794B33A5AFB",
}}
```

Comment: How are you creating this JSON file, and does it appear in your scene correctly without the textures? The file does not look valid to me.

Comment: Thanks for responding Don. The json file was exported via blender and imported into the three.js editor and exported as an object from there (as the original blender json wouldn't work). The object itself works fine, I can see it in the scene correctly, animate it and I can apply materials to it and adjust properties like roughness, metalness, etc. I just can't apply textures

Comment: Oh ok, I just now noticed that you'd removed data from the JSON before posting.. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866748/exporting-a-simple-model-with-texture-from-blender-to-three-js) then, you probably just need to create UVs in Blender before exporting.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll have a look now. Just to be clear, the model I used in blender had no textures, I'm trying to add them separately, just like I did on the plane I placed in the scene where it worked just fine.

Comment: Yeah, even so you’ll need to have UVs in the model if you want to add a texture later. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972672/how-to-apply-texture-to-mesh-without-specifying-uvs-in-geometry-using-three-js

Comment: You beat me to it. I re-exported the model (I still don't think I'm exporting in the correct way) and then replace some elements in the materials (UV) and the texture is now applying. Thank you! I'll post the solution in the article. If you have a good resource in terms of the best setup for exporting from Blender I'd appreciate it. Thanks again.

Comment: Great! Could you post your solution as an answer here, instead? Re: best setup, I've been using [glTF-Blender-Exporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/) and THREE.GLTFLoader usually, not much experience with the JSON exporter.

Comment: I've posted the solution in the article based on the your suggestion as with my reputation I don't believe I can flag a correct answer. I've looked across the documentation but cannot see anything that can tag a comment as the solution. I'll check out the exporter now, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Oh I see, yes you'd need >15 reputation to answer your own question. I can add it then.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do that Don, I've just accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you're not using textures in Blender, you'll need to create UVs in Blender before exporting in order to be able to add textures later.

See:

- [Exporting a simple model with texture from Blender to three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866748/exporting-a-simple-model-with-texture-from-blender-to-three-js)
- [How to apply texture to mesh without specifying UV's in geometry using three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972672/how-to-apply-texture-to-mesh-without-specifying-uvs-in-geometry-using-three-js)

Once you've done that, you should see UVs like this somewhere in your exported JSON, and will be able to add textures in threejs:

```
"uvs":[[0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1]],
```